# How to check if the User entered String is same as that of something

Tags: c

I have this code sample. There is a `scanf` to hold the input `String` values from keyboard (i.e Lotus). But even if I type the word **Lotus** correctly It does not execute the relevant `if` statement. **Is there any problem with my `scanf` function???

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        char landType,houseType[100],wantToContinue,wantToContinue2;
        float installment;
        wantToContinue='Y';
        while(wantToContinue == 'Y' || wantToContinue == 'y') {
            printf("Land Type : ");
            scanf(" %c",&landType); 
            if(landType == 'A') {
                printf("Type of House: ");
                scanf(" %s", houseType);
                if(houseType == "Lotus") { 
                   //this won't go inside if statement even if I type Lotus correctly
                    installment=4000000-500000;
                    printf("Monthly Installment : R.s %.2f\n",installment/120);
                    printf("Do you want to Continue?(Y/y or N/n) : ");
                    scanf(" %c",&wantToContinue2);                  
                    if(wantToContinue2 == 'Y' || wantToContinue2 == 'y') {
                        wantToContinue=wantToContinue2;
                        printf("\n");
                    }else{
                        wantToContinue='N';
                    }
                }   
             }
          }
      }
```

Comment: Fix the indentation. It is unreadable

Comment: Well, it's classic.. You can't use `==` to compare strings. Use `strcmp` and friends instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful when comparing two strings in C. You should use the [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) function from the `string.h` library, like so:

```
if(strcmp("Lotus", houseType) == 0)
```

When you write `if(houseType=="Lotus")` you are actually comparing the base address of the two strings and not their actual content.

Comment: And why are we equaling it to the 0? What does that mean?

Comment: The `strcmp` function returns 0 if the two string are the same, < 0 if the first character that differs has a lower value in str1 than in str2, and > 0 if the character has a greater value in str1 than in str2.

Answer (score 0):

In C, strings cannot be compared using `==`. This is because strings are not a basic data type in C, that is C does not inherently understand how to compare them - you must use a function instead.

A standard function for comparing strings in C is `strcmp()`, e.g.:

```
if (strcmp(houseType, "Lotus") == 0)
{
    // do some work if the strings are equal
}
```

To explain further, your initial attempt to compare strings using `housetype == "Lotus"` actually compares the address where the first character of the character array `houseType` is stored with the address where the first character of the character array `"Lotus"` is stored.

This happens because strings in C are just arrays of characters - they are not an inherent data type, C does not, as such, understand the difference between an array of integers and an array of characters, they are all just numbers arranged contiguously somewhere in memory and it treats them as such unless you specifically use code that operates on them as strings instead.